# How many positive integers n can we make with the digits 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, if the number n > 4, 000, 000?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, self-learning

According to my study guide the answer to the exercise,

How many positive integers, (n), can we make with the digits 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, if the number n > 4, 000, 000, :

The total of numbers n > 4, 000, 000 is equal to the number of arrangements of 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7 of size 6; thus,= $\frac{6!}{2!2!} = 180$.

The total of numbers n > 5, 000, 000 is equal to the number of arrangements of 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 of size 6; thus, $ \frac{6!}{2!}= 360$.

The total of numbers n > 6, 000, 000 is equal to the number of arrangements
of 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7 of size 6; thus, $\frac{6!}{2!2!} = 180$

The total of numbers n > 7, 000, 000 is equal to the number of arrangements of 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 of size 6; thus, $\frac{6!}{2!2!}=180$

The total is 3(180) + 360 = 900.

There are a couple of things I don't understand regarding this answer.

1. Why are we getting n > 4,000,000, n > 5,000,000, and so forth?
2. Why are we dropping the 4 from the set of digits when figuring out n > 4,000,000, the 5 from n > 5,000,000, and so on?

I thought I would need to use something like:

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ = $\frac{7!}{(7-2)!}$ to get the answer. I have (7-2)! because the number 3 < 4 and therefore cannot make a number > 4,000,000 but, when using all 7 digits the remaining numbers will create numbers > 7. For example, 4,556,733 > 4,000,000 and 5,567,334 > 4,000,000, but 3,345,567 < 4,000,000.

I hope I explained this properly. Thanks for any insight.

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you have breaks it into cases: A separate case is considered for $4$ being the leading digit, $5$ being the leading digit, and so forth all the way up to $7$. Here I offer this alternate solution:

In total, one can make $\frac{7!}{2! 2!}$ distinct numbers, disregarding the $n > 4,000,000$ condition. We can use complementary counting now -- take the total and subtract $n < 4,000,000$

In this case, $n < 4,000,000$ if and only if  the leading digit is $3$. The number of such numbers with leading digit three is equal to the number of permutations of the digits $3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7$, which is $\frac{6!}{2!}$.

This gives an answer of $\frac{7!}{ 2! 2!} - \frac{6!}{2} = 900$, agreeing with your study guide.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I understand the answer in the study guide better now and your answer also but, I am still unclear on why in some fractions we have either 2!2! or 2!. Could you explain that part?

Comment: How much do you know about combinatorics? One of the first things you learn is that the number of ways to $n$ things is $n!$. However, you also have to account for counting the same cases twice -- in this case, since we have a pair of indistinct $3$s and/or $5$s, you must divide by $2!$ to account for that. If you had a triple of $3$s instead of a double you would divide by $3!$.

Comment: As an explicit example, consider the permutations of $\{x, y, z\}$.  This is $xyz, xzy, yxz, yzx, zxy, zyx$, giving $3! = 6$. However, let's say $x = 1$ and $y = z = 2$. Then this would give us $122, 122, 212, 221, 212, 221$. Clearly, we have double counted each case, so we divide by $2!$ to get $3$ total permutations as our answer.

Comment: I am fairly new to combinatorics and I forgot about the double counting. I've to account for this before when figuring out how many ways there are to rearrange the letters in MISSISSIPPI but forgot about it here. Thanks for clarifying. I really appreciate your help.